# How can I set the id of an element from snippet using lift framework?

Tags: scala, lift

I have to render a dinamic number of elements depending on some rules determined in the snippet. After that I need to react to user interaction in any of this rendered elements. To determine what element is the one that fired the event I decided to read the id of the element.

Eg. Snippet

```
def render = list.view.zipwithindex.map( case (value,index) => "*" #> <button id="{index}">{value}<button>)
```

To get something like this:

```
<button id="1">One</button>
<button id="2">Two</button>
<button id="3">Three</button>
```

The problem is that what I'm getting is something like this:

```
<button id="{index}">One</button>
<button id="{index}">Two</button>
<button id="{index}">Three</button>
```

What's wrong? I have tested using single quotes, double quotes, scaping using """{index}""" and nothing works.

Just as an extra, moving the id as this is a good way of proceeding or theres a fancier way to achieve this using lift?

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just avoid the quotes completely.

Comment: It’s a bit unexpected. I think I’ve wondered about that as well at some point. :)